# How to modify namespace in classes generated with the CTP5 DbContextGenerator template

Tags: entity-framework-ctp5

in my application I have created a EF model from my database. After I created my POCO classes with the CTP5 ADO.NET DbContextGenerator template. By the way I want modify the namespace of the POCO classes generated. 
I tried to modify the namespace of the model (right click on the model->properties->namespace) and the CustomToolNamespace that I found on right clicking on the model file, but nothing. 
Another thing is that if I try to right click on any of my entities in my model, the namespace it's how I want.
Should necessarily modify by hand in any file generated?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CustomToolNamespace on .tt files instead

Comment: You're right!Thanks! But if I want use them separately from the .tt file,in order to avoid accidental rebuilding, I can only create a backup and use it or it's possible to physically detach from these files? I hope you understand.

Comment: The whole point of the template is that your POCO classes can be regenerated. I would advice against copying the generated code somewhere else in order not to regenerate it. If you need to add some logic to your POCO classes you can create a partial class.